# TSQL join to another table with Group By

Tags: t-sql, join, group-by

The pseudo code of what I currently have is

Cost + CostTax = CostActual

However, I need it to be:

Cost + tax - totalSumDiscounts = CostActual

I have a SQL Select statement at joins 3 tables that calculates cost + tax = CostActual.

```
SELECT     dbo.XMP_EventUsers.ID, dbo.XMP_EventUsers.EventID, dbo.XMP_EventUsers.UserID,
CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),dbo.XMP_EventUsers.DateCreated, 100) 
AS DateCreated, CONVERT(VARCHAR, dbo.XMP_Event.Cost, 1) AS Cost, dbo.Users.FirstName, dbo.Users.LastName, 
dbo.XMP_Event.Cost + dbo.XMP_Event.CostTax - dbo.XMP_EventUsers.Paid AS Outstanding, 
dbo.XMP_Event.Cost +     dbo.XMP_Event.CostTax AS CostActual
FROM         dbo.XMP_Event INNER JOIN
dbo.XMP_EventUsers ON dbo.XMP_Event.ID = dbo.XMP_EventUsers.EventID INNER JOIN
dbo.Users ON dbo.XMP_EventUsers.UserID = dbo.Users.UserID
```

Another table records discounts to be applied to the total cost.  This query totals up the discounts to be applied.

```
    SELECT UserID, SUM([Amount]) AS Amount
FROM [dbo].[XMP_EventPromoUsers]
GROUP BY UserID
```

How do I join the 2nd results to the first so that the total number of discount is minuses from the final cost in the select statement for each record?

Thanks for your help!

-R

Example results below for answer 1

Query 1 returns:

```
ID|EventID|UserID|DateCreated|Cost|FirstName|LastName|Outstanding|CostActual|FinalValue|
51|14-----|41----|Aug 11 2011|0.00|John-----|Smith---|-120-------|0.00------|-10-------|
```

Query 2

```
UserID-|Amount----|

41-----|10--------|

96-----|30--------|
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT     
    dbo.XMP_EventUsers.ID, dbo.XMP_EventUsers.EventID, dbo.XMP_EventUsers.UserID,
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(20),dbo.XMP_EventUsers.DateCreated, 100) AS DateCreated, 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR, dbo.XMP_Event.Cost, 1) AS Cost, 
    dbo.Users.FirstName, dbo.Users.LastName, 
    dbo.XMP_Event.Cost + dbo.XMP_Event.CostTax - dbo.XMP_EventUsers.Paid AS Outstanding, 
    dbo.XMP_Event.Cost +     dbo.XMP_Event.CostTax AS CostActual,
    dbo.XMP_Event.cost + dbo.XMP_Event.CostTax - Users2.Amount AS FinalValue
FROM    
    dbo.XMP_Event 
    INNER JOIN dbo.XMP_EventUsers 
        ON dbo.XMP_Event.ID = dbo.XMP_EventUsers.EventID 
    INNER JOIN dbo.Users 
        ON dbo.XMP_EventUsers.UserID = dbo.Users.UserID
    INNER JOIN (SELECT UserID, SUM([Amount]) AS Amount
        FROM [dbo].[XMP_EventPromoUsers]
        GROUP  BY UserID) Users2
        ON dbo.Users.UserID = Users2.UserID
```

Comment: Thanks, However, the 2nd query returns 2 results on its own, but your query returns only one record? Any Ideas?

Comment: Please show the two records returned by your query and the one returned by mine.

Comment: I just posted the results in the question section as an edit. BTW, yes, the price of the item is 0, with a discount of 10. This is not an issue.

Comment: Hm the result for query 2 shows only 2 fields, my query has many more.  But in a nutshell, what my query should return is a record for every combination of user, event, eventuser and eventpromousers.  It appears that there are two records that meet this case user ID's 41 and 96.  So to clarify, what records are returned by *your* second query, the one that returns Sum([Amount])?

Comment: "what records are returned by your second query, the one that returns Sum([Amount])?" yes, Correct. two results. UserID 41 & 96.

Comment: Then I don't understand what the issue is.  If your second query returns two records, then joining it to the first query should also return two records, one for user 41, one for user 96.

Comment: Seems to be a logical error. The USERID that was being passed by the App was incorrect. Fixed that, everything works perfectly. Thank you

Comment: Great.  I'm glad I could help!  The main thing here is to know how/when to use nested queries.